# sqlite app keeps crashing

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

So I'm trying to set up a basic database with clients that have 4 fields, id, firstname, lastname and age. I have one method that puts data in and one that logs it out to make sure it's working. Here is what I have:

Right at the beginning of the MainActivity class:

```
SQLiteDatabase clientsDatabase;
```

In my onCreate method:

```
try
{
    clientsDatabase = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Clients", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    clientsDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clients (id INT(3), fName VARCHAR, lName VARCHAR, age INT(3))");
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And my method that puts new data in is:

```
public void addMember(int id, String f, String l, int a)
{
    clientsDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO clients (id, fName, lName, age) VALUES (" + id + ", '" + f + "', '" + l + "', " + a + ")");
}
```

And my method that logs the data out based on the id you give to it is:

```
public void printMember(int id)
{
    Cursor c = clientsDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id = " + Integer.toString(id), null);

    int idIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
    int fNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("fName");
    int lNameIndex = c.getColumnIndex("lName");
    int ageIndex = c.getColumnIndex("age");

    c.moveToFirst();

    while (c != null)
    {
        Log.i("Results - id", Integer.toString(c.getInt(idIndex)));
        Log.i("Results - First name", c.getString(fNameIndex));
        Log.i("Results - Last name", c.getString(lNameIndex));
        Log.i("Results - Age", Integer.toString(c.getInt(ageIndex)));

        c.moveToNext();
    }

    c.close();

}
```

And FINALLY! I set up a button with the 'onClick' method of:

```
public void logUser(View view)
{
    addMember(1, "Clark", "Kent", 30);
    printMember(1);
}
```

The emulator crashes when I press the button, and this is what shows up in the logs(It was A LOT, so I didn't wanna make this post any longer, so I put some screenshots):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OpV4.jpg

The weird thing is *IT IS* logging the correct information. It just crashes afterward for some reason.

And I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I really need to get this way to work, so any help is appreciated

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your logcat. You may [edit] your question to include it

Comment: The Stacktrace tells you, that the Exception happened in line 54 of your MainActivity class. It's something about an IdexOutOfBounds, so check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your while loop to

```
while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
    ...
}
```

because c never gets null, it is just moved down and down until it's out of rows in the database.

Comment: You're welcome. Please also officially accept my answer by ticking the checkmark on the left of the answer :-)

Comment: I was trying to, but there is a 5 minute limit before I could press it. Now it's done! Thanks again :)